# How to properly set up Python daemon in Lightsail via Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-lightsail

I'm trying to set up a daemon to run the web server for a site that I'm working on in a light sail box. I've successfully got the frontend working with npm, but the backend daemon is giving me nothing but problems.

```
[Unit]
Description=Server.py-start
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/ifd/src/backend
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -m server.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Which is outputting the error code:

```
ubuntu@ip-random-nums: $ sudo systemctl status pyserver.service
● pyserver.service - Server.py-start
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pyserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-04-11 20:10:34 UTC; 1s ago
    Process: 266804 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -m server.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 266804 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I'm reloading the daemon, but cannot figure out what is wrong with this file.

Using `which python` points to /usr/bin/python3 as the executable. I modified it to:
`/usr/bin/python3 -m /home/ubuntu/ifd/src/backend/server.py` and it executed once and seemed to be running, but again broke.

`sudo journalctl -u pyserver.service` yields:

```
Apr 10 22:39:48 ip-numbers systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/pyserver.service:8: Executable "python" not found in path "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/>
Apr 10 22:39:48 ip-numbers systemd[1]: pyserver.service: Unit configuration has fatal error, unit will not be started.
Apr 10 23:24:13 ip-numbers systemd[1]: Started Server.py start.
```

Which points that python is not found in path, but that seems to contradict the `which python3` statement.

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas, it would be appreciated